# Handling multiple search fields in cypher or py2neo

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Just getting started with cypher. Trying to understand best way to handle this case. I need to query database based on several search fields(not always present). Wondering what's the best way to handle it. For e.g I collect data from html post request

```
storeName = request.form['storeName']
storeCountry = request.form['storeCountry']       
storeState = request.form['storeState']       
storeCity = request.form['storeState']
```

I'm using flask framework, so defined this function with py2neo to handle search fields. Not sure if I got it right but if all fields are set correctly, hopefully, something like this should work fine

```
def get_search_results(skipNumber,limitNumber, storeName, storeCountry,storeState, storeCity):
        query = """
        MATCH (store:store) WHERE store.name = {storeName}
        MATCH (store:store)-[:IS_IN_COUNTRY]->(c:Country) WHERE c.name = {storeCountry}
        MATCH (store:store)-[:IS_IN_STATE]->(s:State) WHERE s.name = {storeState}
        MATCH (store:store)-[:IS_IN_CITY]->(ct:City) WHERE ct.name = {storeCity}

        RETURN user SKIP {skip} LIMIT {limit}
        """

        return graph.cypher.execute(query, skip=skipNumber, limit=limitNumber, storeName=storeName, storeCountry=storeCountry, storeState=storeState, storeCity=storeCity)
```

I would like to handle cases where users only submit one or two fields. 
For e.g 
1. if users only submit store name, then I should be able to return all the nodes with that store name.
2. If users only submit store name and country. Return all the stores nodes in that country 
3. If users only submit store name, country and state. Return all the stores nodes in that country and state

Is it possible to write a generic cypher query to handle such scenarios  i.e ignore cases where field is not set or is None or I need to write different queries to handle each case ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't dynamically assemble pieces of your query based on which parameters are null or not?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly. You mean only pass parameters to def get_search_results(..) which are not null ? I can do that but it will require lot of pre-processing if there are large number of search parameters. For e.g 15 search parameters plus different combination of them. I was wondering if it easier to handle with cypher with some combination of logical operators and NULL

Comment: What I mean is that when you're assembling the query itself, only including the relevant MATCH line if the relevant parameter is null. So if the storeCountry parameter is null, you don't append the line for that MATCH and corresponding WHERE into your query string.

Comment: That's part I'm not sure how to do. Are there any examples somewhere I can refer to ?

Comment: I'm sure there are. This should just be a an application of using if statements in python, and under certain conditions, concatenating your query string with the relevant line, probably with the += operator.